# Query through multiple resultSet output from a Stored Procedure to get the value of a column

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, tomcat7

A stored Procedure is returning three Result sets.I want a value from of a column from the third result Set.I would like to loop through the result sets and get the value of that column.

```
Ex: lets say SP returns three tables.
table 1:
 Sno,Col_val1,Col_Val 2
table2:
Sno,Col_val11,Col_Val 22
table 3:
Sno,Col_val111,Col_Val 222
```

the above are output of a SP.

i want the value of Col_val111.how to do the following in java?

Answer (score 1):

This might help. The example was given [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvjdmlt.htm) but reproduced below in case of link rot:

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
int i;
String s;
...
cstmt.execute();                        // Call the stored procedure  
rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the first result set 
while (rs.next()) {                     // Position the cursor
 i = rs.getInt(1);                      // Retrieve current result set value
 System.out.println("Value from first result set = " + i);  
                                        // Print the value
}
cstmt.getMoreResults();                 // Point to the second result set
                                        // and close the first result set
rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the second result set 
while (rs.next()) {                     // Position the cursor 
 s = rs.getString(1);                   // Retrieve current result set value
 System.out.println("Value from second result set = " + s); 
                                        // Print the value
}
rs.close();                             // Close the result set
cstmt.close();                          // Close the statement
```

Comment: Thank you .Got the base logic from your example. I modified it accordingly and is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the next result set using [Statement.getMoreResults()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) and [Statement.getResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29).

```
Statement stmt = // prepare the statement
stmt.execute();
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    stmt.getMoreResults();
}
thirdResultset = stmt.getResultSet();
// process the third resultset
```

... plus a ton of code to check that all is going well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which i made just for fetching the column value of the last table.Thanks nick and Jiri.

```
CallableStatement cal = null;
String sp_call = "{call "+SP_Name+" (?,?,?)" +"}";
cal= connection.prepareCall(sp_call);
cal.setString(1,param1);
cal.setInt(2,param2);
cal.setInt(3,param3);
ResultSet res =null;
cal.execute();
int rs_count = 0;
while(rs_count<3)
{
    if(i<2){cal.getMoreResults();rs = cal.getResultSet();rs_count++;continue;}
    else{return rs; }
}
```